# input to sklearn pipeline from previous step and from the fitted data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a sklearn pipeline like the following:

```
features = Pipeline([
        ('feats_A', Function_transformer_A())
        ('feats_B', Function_transformer_B())
    ])
features.fit(X)
```

The input to `feats_A` is the fitted data `X`. And, the input to `feats_B` is the output from `feats_A`.

Instead, I want to be the input to `feats_B` the fitted data `X` and the output from `feats_A`, together. Given that, these two different data matrices could have different dimensions; `Function_transformer_A` applies aggregation to process the input data.

Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you should just use the ``.fit`` and ``.transform()`` method of your transformers individually instead of concatenating them in a Pipeline? This way you can pass whatever input data you want

Comment: I did it in a similar way, two separate transformers and a passed `feats_A` as parameter to `feats_B` and I fit it inside. But I was asking to check if there is another way, magical function, etc. can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using FeatureUnion

```
def blank(df):
    return df

subpipe = FeatureUnion(
        [('prep_data', Function_transformer(blank)),
        ('feats_A', Function_transformer_A())])
        
features = Pipeline([

        ('subpipe', subpipe)
        ('feats_B', Function_transformer_B())
    ])
```